# Add Subject Conversion Tracking Link

Tags: marketing-cloud

In reference to this link [Track mailto links](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/95341/track-mailto-links)

Has anyone attempted to add a Subject to the MailTo: link?

I tried the default setting of `?email=user@user.com?subject=My Subject Here` 
but the concat feature is not separating the two values for the appropriate spots.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the question mark only for the first parameter, the following ones need to be separated by ampersands like this:

```
?email=user@user.com&subject=subjecttext
```

*EDIT:* If you use the code from the shared question, you need to retrieve the query parameters separately:

```js
%%[
    Var @email, @subject
    Set @email = QueryParameter('email')
    Set @subject QueryParameter('subject')

    Redirect(Concat('mailto:', @email, '?subject=', @subject))
]%%
```

Comment: Thanks Markus!  Just gave that a try, and the default mail client opens, but nothing populates for the To: field or the Subject field.

Comment: @DaveyGreene Please share the exact code you use, so isolating an issue is easier. Thank you! If you are using the exact code of the linked resource you shared, check out my updated answer.